# Bootstrap 4: How to hide a column once grid system's breakpoint is reached?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

Given the following BS4 layout, how can I make Column 3 disappear instead of being stacked right at the bottom of the viewport once the breakpoint is reached.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="col1" class="col-md-3">
      I am Column 1
    </div>           
    <div id="col2" class="col-md-4">
        I am Column 2
    </div>
    <div id="col3" class="col-md-5">
        I am Column 3, I should disappear once the breakpoint is reached!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using vanilla CSS, I would do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #col3 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

However, I want a solution which will work even if further down the road I decide to change the minimum width to `sm`, `lg` or `xl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/display/#hiding-elements), you should use Display Property Utilities like this:

```
<div id="col3" class="col-md-5 d-sm-none d-md-block">
    I am Column 3, I should disappear once the breakpoint is reached!
</div>
```

Comment: Seem to have missed this when going over the docs! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Pay attention to the Utilities. They are so useful.